# Can I reference other properties during object declaration in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do something like this:

```
var obj = {
    a: 5,
    b: this.a + 1
}
```

(instead of 5 there is a function which I don't want to execute twice that returns a number)

I can rewrite it to assign `obj.b` later from `obj.a`, but can I do it right away during declaration?

Comment: `javascript: var obj = {a: 5, b: this.a + 1}; alert(obj.b);` alerts NaN, so no.

Comment: Recently asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations, also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself

Answer (score 50, accepted):

No. `this` in JavaScript does not work like you think it does. `this` in this case refers to the global object.

There are only 3 cases in which the value `this` gets set:

**The Function Case**

```
foo();
```

Here `this` will refer to the *global* object.

**The Method Case**

```
test.foo();
```

In this example `this` will refer to `test`.

**The Constructor Case**

```
new foo();
```

A function call that's preceded by the `new` keyword acts as a constructor. Inside the function `this` will refer to a newly
created `Object`.

Everywhere else, `this` refers to the global object.

Comment: +1 Nice answer. Only I'd add the case when `this` is set explicitly using the function or method case via `.call()` or `.apply()`. (Perhaps more of a subset of those two cases.)

Comment: Yes, those could be added, but they are a bit out of scope here IMO, although I'll add them to my docs.

Comment: I agree. I think your answer covers the necessary bases for the question.

Comment: @user113716 Don't forget `.bind(...)`

Comment: `this` in "The Function Case"  refer to the parent object, not the global object: `const obj = { a: 5, b: function foo() { return this.a + 1; } };`

Comment: @Aria Pahlavan `this` in this context is `undefined`

Answer (score 14):

There are several ways to accomplish this; this is what I would use:

```
function Obj() {
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = this.a + 1;
    // return this; // commented out because this happens automatically
}

var o = new Obj();
o.b; // === 6
```

Answer (score 9):

This should return the correct values:

```
function () {
   var aVar = 5;
   var bVar = aVar + 1;

return {
    a : aVar,
    b : bVar;  
}
}();
```

Answer (score 5):

As it turns out you can't reference an object inside another object unless the first   one is a function. But you can do it this way.

```
    var obj = {
        a: 5
    }

    obj.b = obj.a + 1; // create field b in runtime and assign it's value
```

If you console.log(obj) you will have

```
   obj = {
        a: 5,
        b: 6
     }
```

This way you keep the object literal structure for the remaining part of the code

Answer (score 2):

No, in your example, the value of `this` doesn't refer to the object literal.

You'll need to assign a value to `b` after the object has been created in order to base it on another property in `obj`.

Answer (score 2):

No. `this` will take the same meaning as it would outside the definition.

Answer (score 2):

in chrome debugger

```
> var o = {a: 5, b: this.a+1}
undefined
> o.b
NaN
> o.a
5
```