# Setting two properties equal in the declaration

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I want to set two properties equal to each other in one object. Here's an example:

```
var obj = { // I want to do something like this
    a: function() { ... },
    b: alert,
    c: a
};
```

Obviously that doesn't work and I have to do something like this:

```
var obj = {
    a: function() { ... },
    b: alert,
};
obj.c = obj.a;
```

Is there any way to do that in the declaration?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618541/can-i-reference-other-properties-during-object-declaration-in-javascript, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = { 
    a: function() { alert("hello")},
    b: alert,
    c: function(){return this.a()}
};

obj.c();
```

As SLaks mentioned, this won't work if the functions have properties (eg, prototype or arguments.callee).

Comment: This won't work if the functions have properties (eg, `prototype` or `arguments.callee`).

Answer (score 1):

You can declare the function first and use it with `a` & `c`:

```
function f() { ... }

var obj = {
    a: f,
    b: alert,
    c: f
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put the value into a separate variable:

```
var temp = function() { ... };
var obj = { // I want to do something like this
    a: temp,
    b: alert,
    c: temp
};
```

However, you cannot do any better than that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do everything inside the object initializer, then you can have one property call the function from the other and relay any arguments using the Function.arguments property:

```
var obj = { 
    a: function() { ... },
    b: alert,
    c: function() { return this.a(arguments); }
};
```

However, your best bet might be to create a variable containing the anonymous function first, then assign its value to both properties in your object initializer:

```
var fn = function() { ... };
var obj = {
    a: fn,
    b: alert,
    c: fn
};
```

You can also do something like this, but I'd go with the approach one above:

```
var obj = { b: alert };
obj.a = obj.c = function() { ... };
```