# Cannot access the variable in the object

Tags: javascript

I want to access the variable in the object, something like below:

```
var menuSetup = {
    m : [100,200],
    height: m[0], // m is not defined
}


var menuSetup = {
    m : [100,200],
    height: this.m[0], // I tried this, still failed
}
```

So can I access the variable in the object?

Comment: You can't, that's about it.

Comment: You can't do that unfortunately...

Comment: You could define a variable outside of the object and use that in both places.  http://jsfiddle.net/5taBt/

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It would cause cluttering. What you really want here is an object with a *method* `height()` that returned the value you want.

Comment: @Casey Falk this is just an example

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase: why would you *ever* want to do this? This is *begging* for trouble since JavaScript is reference-based.

Comment: @Casey Falk Sorry, I am just a newbie. Yes, I know the problem, thanks!

Comment: No worries! It's just best to be aware of dangers early on so you don't fall down the rabbit hole. ;) It's good to be curious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't do that. This is because the properties of `menuSetup` haven't been defined yet. For example,

```
var menuSetup = {
  m: [100, 200],
  height: menuSetup.m[0]
};
```

will through (in chrome) `TypeError: Cannot read property 'm' of undefined` because `menuSetup` is just undefined (because it was hoisted by the `var` declaration)

The only two ways I can think of is to

a) Save `m` as a variable before. For example:

```
var m = [100, 200];
var menuSetup = {
  m: m,
  height: m[0]
}
```

b) Use a method instead of a variable and execute it.

```
var menuSetup = {
  m: [100, 200],
  height: function() { return this.m[0]; }
}
```

Then, when you get `menuSetup.height`, you would actually do `menuSetup.height()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var MenuSetup = function() {
    this.m =  [100,200];
    this.height = this.m[0];
}

var menuSetup = new MenuSetup();
console.log(MenuSetup.height);
```

Comment: I always get beat out by about 15 seconds :P

Comment: Shouldn't the constructor start with a capital letter and the instance start with the lower i.e. `var menuSetup = new MenuSetup()`?

Comment: @soktinpk good point, I was keeping OP casing but you're right this is different and merit changing.

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you're doing it. In JavaScript you cannot reference another property while creating the same object, because the object doesn't yet exist until after the closing `}` at the end.

You could use a constructor function instead though, as explained in answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618541/can-i-reference-other-properties-during-object-declaration-in-javascript) similar question.

```
function MenuSetup() {
    this.m = [100, 200];
    this.height = this.m[0];
}

var menu = new MenuSetup();
console.log(menu.height) //100
```