# Value of this inside arrow function inside an Object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I thought I understood the relationship between `this` and arrow functions but the following snippet is making me question my understanding.

```
let person = {
  name: 'Jim',
  sayName: () => {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};

person.sayName();
```

I understand that arrow functions capture the `this` value of the enclosing context. I was expecting `this` would be the object but instead it is `Window`.

Can someone help me understand why this is the case?

Comment: In your example `this` will be undefined if you want to get the value of name either use the normal function syntax **or** reference the object name so it's `person.name`

Comment: An `Object` literal doesn't create an enclosing context. Only the body of a normal function does.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your understanding of arrow functions is mostly correct: Arrow functions have a lexical `this` and its value within the arrow function is determined by the surrounding scope.

You probably assume that `this` gets a different value within the `person` object literal. [This is not the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618541/can-i-reference-other-properties-during-object-declaration-in-javascript).

So let's see what `this` refers to in your (global) scope:

```js
console.log(this === window); // true

let person = {
  name: 'Jim',
  test: console.log(this === window), // true
  sayName: () => {
    console.log(this === window); // true
  }
};

person.sayName();
```

As you can see, when the arrow function assigned to `sayName` is created, `this` refers to the `window` object.

Answer (score 9):

TLDR;

Think of it this way, "if I used non arrow function, what would be `this`" From that you can then recall that `this` in an arrow function would be the more outer scope `this` compared to its counterpart.

**Example**

```js
let arrow = {
  test: () => {
    console.log('arrow: this === window...', this === window);
  }
};

let nonarrow = {
  test: function() {
    console.log('non-arrow: this === window...', this === window);
  }
};

arrow.test()
nonarrow.test();
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no binding of "this", so here is a working version of what you tried:

```
let person = {
  name: 'Jimmy the Greek',
  sayName: (obj) => {
    console.log(obj.name);
  }
};

person.sayName(person);
```

More to read on [Mozilla DEV](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).