# Can't access this directly on exported module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am not sure if JS modules are supposed to work like this, but it doesn't make sense. I am using React and I would like to export an object from one module and then call methods on that object. This work well so far, however, the issue is that inside the invoked method, `this` doesn't point to the object on which it was invoked, and I can't access other member methods. Here is an example:

```
export let localService = {
     getData: () => {
        console.log(this);
        this.testMethod();
     },

    testMethod: () => {

    }
};
```

In the other file I import the object and invoke the method:

```
import {localService} from '../../localService.js';

localService.getData();
```

Now things get strange, inside the `getData` I can't access `this.testMethod()` directly because `this` is sort of different, here's the output of `console.log(this)`

[image]

and of course invoking `this.testMethod()` throws an error saying that method doesn't exist. I am able to access `testMethod()` like this: `this.a.testMethod()` , but where does this `a` come from? So is this normal behavior, or maybe it's React's fault ?

Comment: Review how arrow functions affect `this`: [Value of this inside arrow function inside an Object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44080949). The `a` is likely a byproduct of whatever packaging software you're using (likely Webpack if you're using React's default).

Comment: could you please post complete code ?

Comment: @Isa42999 that's the complete code. Heretic you're correct, without arrow functions it work's as expected, thanks!.

Comment: what you want to achieve here ? calling `localService.getData();` should trigger `testMethod` ?

Answer (score 0):

now your `localService` is type of json data that's the reason you are getting `a` when you console, you can't call other functions there.

you have to create each functions individually.

create `localService.js` with below content.

```
export const getData = () => {
    console.log("getData");
    testMethod();
};

export const testMethod = () => {
    console.log("testMethod");
};
```

import `localService.js` like this.

```
import * as localService from '../../localService.js';
```

now you can call `localService.getData()`