# TypeError: this.isModified is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I am facing a weird issue.

The below code throws error and it uses arrow function

```
UserSchema.pre('save', next => {
  const SALT_FACTOR = 5;

  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      this.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

The below code works fine and it uses normal function.

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  const SALT_FACTOR = 5;

  if (!this.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(SALT_FACTOR, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, null, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      this.password = hash;
      next();
    });
  });
});
```

Anyone has an idea why arrow function throws below error?

> TypeError: this.isModified is not a function

Comment: Well, the arrow function will have `this` bound to its lexical scope. So, I imagine it's probably not going to be the `this` you want.

Comment: The way `this` is handled is one of the fundamental differences between `=>` functions and traditional functions.

Answer (score 0):

You want might to reference this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/44080978/1971378. 
`gist`: arrow functions seal `this` when defined.