# 'this' keyword do not refer to its own object

Tags: this, javascript-objects

```
let obj = {
    a:2,
    b: this.a,
};

console.log(obj.a); //outputs 2
console.log(obj.b); //outputs undefined
```

Why can't I access one property of an object from another property within the same object? What's the way around this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I reference other properties during object declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618541/can-i-reference-other-properties-during-object-declaration-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

It's a scope issue. Put the `b` outside of the object:

```js
let obj = {
   a:2
}

obj.b = obj.a;
console.log(obj.a);
console.log(obj.b);
```

You can't use a `this` keyword before you've declared the variable.