# How to reference an object inside itself?

Tags: javascript

How to reference an object inside itself?

As you can see below I'm creating an unnamed object inside the console.log

```
    console.log({
      x: 2,
      y: this.x * 2,
    });
```

I'm not assigning it to any variable.

So I want a way to access it's property `x` inside itself like calling `this.x`.

However the above approach is not working.

I'm getting a `NAN` error.

**NOTE** I don't want it to assign to a variable/ create using a function constructor/ prototype.

Comment: Just use `2`
If it's a variable, use the variable

Comment: If I just use the variable then it throws x not defined error... Hope you got my point.

Comment: I just want to access a property/variable of an object within itself... something like we do with a class ... like accessing own props using this keyword..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I reference other properties during object declaration in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4618541/can-i-reference-other-properties-during-object-declaration-in-javascript)

Comment: I want to achieve that with just a raw object.. (i.e. without any contructor/ prototype.)

Comment: well you can't...

Comment: There is no mechanism that allows an "under construction" object to be referenced inside the object initializer. You can partially construct the object and then use separate statements to add properties based on the values of other properties, or you can use the getter approach as suggested in the answer below to defer computation to the point where a property value is accessed.

Answer (score 5):

You could write `y` with a [getter method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get):

> The **`get`** syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.

```js
console.log({
    x: 2,
    get y() { return this.x * 2 },
});
```

Comment: is this javascript?

Comment: I mean if I try it from my side .. I'm only getting {x:2} .... nothing else!

Comment: Assign it to an object like: `var obj = {  x: 2,  get y() { return this.x * 2 }};`  Then call it: `obj[y]`

Comment: Actually I'm inside another class... so I thing this refers to that parent object... How can I solve this?

Comment: How can I do it without assigning ??

Comment: What I want to achieve is that something like this```{
  "x": 2,
  "y": 4
}```.... so what ever the value of x double that to get the value of y && the object should contain both x and y

Comment: JavaScript provides no direct way of doing that.

Comment: This is the best solution your going to get for what you want... For the context issue, you could create a function that returns the object as described here.

Comment: There must be a way... we can do this in a class and a function...

Comment: There is no natural law of the universe that would insist that "there must be a way". In JavaScript, there is not a way.

Comment: My bad... maybe I'm wrong! sorry... it may not be possible... I thought it would be!

Comment: Note that the API when using a getter looks exactly like a property access... which appears to be what you want... `const o = { x: 2, get y() { return x * 2} }; console.log(o.y) // 4`

Answer (score 0):

You could set your initial property first, and then the property that references it later:

```js
const obj = {'x':2};
obj.y = obj.x*2;
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Without any context about *why* you need to do it this way, it's hard to give you a good answer.

Comment: I wanna do it in one go... I don't wanna assign to a variable..

Comment: Inside the object initializer, the object does not yet exist. The language provides no way of referring to the object until *after* the initializer is evaluated.

Comment: My bad... maybe I'm wrong! sorry... it may not be possible... I thought it would be!

Comment: If you wanna do it in one go, and you already know what the value of `x` is going to be as you're initializing it, then make `y` the value of 2 times that, without referencing x.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a function that will take the first object as first arg and a callback in the second, then in the callback you would work on the things you set, return what you want, and merge it back to the original object.

```
console.log(mergeFunction({
      x: 2
   }, (o) => { return { 
      y: o.x * 2 
   }}
}));
```

Not pretty, but likely the best you can do if you want it in "one go".

You get to implement mergeFunction yourself.