# JavaScript object literal scope

Tags: javascript, object, scope, literals

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a Javascript object refer to values in itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself)

I have some JS as follows:

```
var Wrap = {

    Inner : {

        site_base : "http://site.com/",
        marker_purple : site_base + "images/icon/marker-puple.png"
    }
}
```

`site_base` is undefined. 
`Wrap.Inner.site_base` is undefined.

How can I access my values within the same object?

Comment: You can't.  You'd have to do that in a separate statement: `Wrap.Inner.marker_purple = Wrap.Inner.site_base + ...`

Comment: Nope; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself

Comment: Object literals do not define a scope, functions do for variables.

Answer (score 3):

The error you have is due to the fact that `site_base` is undefined, so object creation fails.

Try this:

```
var site_base = "http://site.com/";

var Wrap = {
    Inner : {
        site_base : site_base,
        marker_purple : site_base + "images/icon/marker-puple.png"
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy with this approach - thank you. I'll accept as soon as I'm allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Alternative to a separate statement:

```
var Wrap = { // variable names starting with capital letters make me uncomfortable
  Inner: function() {
    var base = "http://site.com/";
    return {
      site_base: base,
      marker_purple: base + "images/icon/marker-purple.png"
    };
  }()
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it in different statements as the object does not exist yet.

```
var Wrap = {
    Inner:{
        site_base: "http://site.com/"
    }
};
Wrap.Inner.marker_purple = Wrap.Inner.site_base + "images/icon/marker-puple.png"
```

Comment: I know what you mean, but "on different lines" doesn't sit well with me. Although it probably should, given the auto statement termination nature of JavaScript engines in general.

Answer (score 0):

Use a closure within an [Immediately Invoked Function Expression](http://cnx.org/content/m43269/latest/):

```
var Wrap = (function(){
  var site_base = "http://site.com/"
  return {
      Inner: {marker_purple : site_base + "images/icon/marker-puple.png"}
  };
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the other answers, you can not access object properties, before the object is actually created. Thus your code fails.

When using ECMAScript 5 and the `Object.create()` function, however, you can mimic the behavior you want by using the `get()` function like this:

```
var Wrap ={
  Inner: Object.create(Object.prototype, {

    site_base: { writable:true, configurable:true, value: "http://site.com/" },

    marker_purple: {
      get: function() { return this.site_base + "images/icon/marker-puple.png" }
    }
  })
};
```

More information can be found on MDN, e.g. on browser support

- [`Object.create()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)
- [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

Answer (score 0):

Is it valid?

```
marker_purple : this.site_base + "images/icon/marker-puple.png"
```

EDIT: I can test it and it works fine btw.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: No, it isn't valid. Don't post wild guesses as answers when you can easily test them.