# Javascript and referencing one namespace property from another

Tags: javascript, namespaces

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can a Javascript object refer to values in itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself)

Let's say I have:

```
var myNamespace = {
      _prop1: 'hello',
      _prop2: _prop1 + ' you!'
};
```

I'm just now finding out that this will error on `_prop2` at load.

I can't understand why this doesn't work, I've worked around it in my code but I would still like to understand.

Comment: Bear in mind that the thing you're declaring doesn't actually exist until the final }; in your code above because this isn't compiled - so the error you will get (_prop1 is undefined) is really telling you the entire truth of the matter!

Comment: In javascript, variable scopes works a little bit differently than in C or other languages. When you ask for a variable, it checks if it as been declared as a var in the current scope (between the same brackets) or if it is a variable of the global object (window in a browser context). Here _prop1 as not been declared as a var in the same context, and so cannot be accessed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try and set prop2 the object hasn't initialised so the value of prop1 and mynamespace are both undefined.

There are a couple of ways to achieve what you want, one way would be to create prop2 as a function so it can dynamically get the value of prop1

```
var myNamespace = {
      _prop1: 'hello',
      _prop2: function(){ return this._prop1 + ' you!' }
};
```

Another way would be to set prop2 after myNamespace has been initialised

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this:

```
var myNamespace = {
    _prop1: 'hello'
};
myNamespace._prop2: myNamespace._prop1 + ' you!';
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do

```
var myNamespace = {
      _prop1: 'hello',
      _prop2: myNamespace._prop1 + ' you!'
};
```

I don't think it's possible to do it any other way in the declaration (eg: using "self" or "this" doesn't work)

Comment: Actually I tried this as well and I still get an undefined error. It's really weird. Could it be chrome? I'll try a different browser and report back.

Comment: Nope, not in Firefox either

Comment: This would work if you did something like
    
    var myNamespace = {};
    myNamespace = {
        _prop1: 'hello',
        _prop2: myNamespace._prop1 + ' you!'
    };

Comment: This answer definitely doesn't work. You have to do it as a two-step process as per bfavaretto's answer.