# Multiple urls in environment.ts file in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a development environment in angular and need to add URLs into parts but unfortunately, I can't append the value which is declared inside the environment file.

```ts
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    apiRootUrl:  'https://abcd.in/api',
    apiPublicUrl: 'public',
    apiCurrentVersion: 'v1',
    CONST_SLASH: '/',
    apiSsoUrl: 'sso',
    apiBaseUrl: environment.apiRootUrl + environment.CONST_SLASH + environment.apiPublicUrl +                                   
                environment.CONST_SLASH + environment.apiCurrentVersion + environment.CONST_SLASH + 
                environment.apiSsoUrl 
};
```

But in the `apiBaseUrl` it's showing an error:

```
Block-scoped variable 'environment' used before its declaration.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't set a property to another property in the same object. You can read more here: [I need to set a json object property in a object, then reference that property from another object in the same object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16492703/i-need-to-set-a-json-object-property-in-a-object-then-reference-that-property-f)

A solution would be to create a model or a service, where you create the baseUrl by accessing the environment properties.

Comment: Yes I already create a service to append these properties but, can't we concate these properties inside the "envirnment.ts" file ?

Comment: No, that is not possible, please have a look at the solution in the link I postet. As noted there "the object has to be initialized before its values can be referred to".

Comment: so what if I make environmental object as a class in "envirnment.ts" file