# Convert code to JS Object Literal Pattern

Tags: javascript, oop, audiocontext

I want to start writing better code and I have come to understand that putting everything relevant to a particular piece of functionality inside an object is a good idea.

Edit: I've tried to take on board the concept in @SoftwareEngineer171's answer. Now I have this:

```
var app = {
    audioCtx : new(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(),

    init : function () {
        oscillator = app.audioCtx.createOscillator();
        oscillator.type = 'square';
        oscillator.frequency.value = 3000; // value in hertz
        oscillator.start();
    }
} // app object close

app.init();
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone explain why?

I want to use this code as part of an application, but placed inside an object literal:

```
var context = new AudioContext(), 
    gainNode = context.createGain(), 
    oscillator = context.createOscillator();

gainNode.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.frequency.value = 440;
oscillator.connect(gainNode);
oscillator.start();
```

However, when I have tried, I run into problems of the kind mentioned [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself)

I want the code to begin like this:

```
var app = {
    context : new AudioContext(),
    ...
}
```

Any help much appreciated as usual.

Comment: Why? For what purpose?

Comment: "*putting everything relevant to a particular piece of functionality inside an object is a good idea*" - no, it's not. At least not in general.

Comment: Where else are you going to use any of these three variables? Is this your whole code? What do you think will you gain from an `app` object?

Comment: I want to use an app object because the code given is just a tiny but essential part of what will be a much larger application. I'm trying to follow some of the ideas about modular coding presented for example here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-NYyst_tiY&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABs-wDaaxChu82q_xQgUb4f&index=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is not *a particular piece of functionality*, but you can do it in several ways. For example, if you want to write the following object

```
var obj = {
    a: 5,
    b: 7,
    c: a + b
};
```

it will throw an `ReferenceError`. To avoid it, rewrite the syntax as following

```
var obj = {
    a: 5,
    b: 7,
    init(){
        this.c = this.a + this.b;
        return this;
    }
}.init();
```

You can also do it using class

```
var obj = new class{
    constructor(){
        this.a = 5;
        this.b = 7;
        this.c = this.a + this.b;
    }
}();
```

or even using constructor function

```
var obj = new function(){
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 7;
    this.c = this.a + this.b;
}();
```

**Edit**

In your case, audio context script will look like this (see also [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SoftwareEngineer171/w4dbk2e2/)):

```
var app = {
  context: new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)(),
  gainNode: null,
  oscillator: null,
  init(){
    this.gainNode = this.context.createGain();
    this.oscillator = this.context.createOscillator();
    this.gainNode.connect(this.context.destination);
    this.oscillator.frequency.value = 440;
    this.oscillator.connect(this.gainNode);
    this.oscillator.start();
  }
};

app.init();
```

Comment: I have tried to apply this approach, and edited my question accordingly.

Comment: @Robin Your approach is wrong. See my answer, I added the exact code you are looking for.