# Can't do math operation in property declaration?

Tags: javascript, object

JavaScript learner here: given this object:

```js
var ivan = {
    name: 'Ivan',
    yearOfBirth: 1973,
    age: 2017 - this.yearOfBirth
}

console.log(ivan.age);
```

Why the console.log says `NaN`? Can't I do simple math operations in property declaration? if not, why?

Comment: `this.yearOfBirth` is not defined yet ...

Comment: `this` does not refer to the object you are in the process of creating either.

Comment: You can find the answer to your solution on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happen since `this.yearOfBirth` is not defined yet, You could use anonymous function as a constructor :

```js
var ivan = new function() {
    this.name = 'Ivan',
    this.yearOfBirth = 1973,
    this.age = 2017 - this.yearOfBirth
};
console.log(ivan.age);
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution is too advanced for me at the moment (I'm following a Javascript course) but I think I got the explanation: so, when I define the object, "this" doesn't exists yet... it starts existing when I "use" somehow the object, right?

Comment: Oh, and more: "this" can be used only inside object methods, right? Using it on properties like my not-working example is a mess,as it turns out, isn't it?