# Assign an object property value to another property while declaring the object

Tags: javascript, object, declaration

I have the following Javascript code:

```
var container = {
  first: {
    a: 1,
    b: 'someString'
  },

  second: Object.assign({
      c: 34,
      d: 'something else'
    },
    this.first
  )
}

console.log(container)
```

This prints:

```
{ first: { a: 1, b: 'someString' },
  second: { c: 34, d: 'something else' } }
```

However, I would like it to be:

```
{ first: { a: 1, b: 'someString' },
  second: { c: 34, d: 'something else', a: 1, b: 'someString'} }
```

So I would like all the (key, value) pairs from `first` to also be present in `second`. How can that be done?

Comment: You can [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself)

Comment: `this.first` does not exist on time of assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't refer to an object before it exists, which is what you're trying to do. But you can do this:

```js
var first = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'someString'
};

var container = {
  first: first,

  second: Object.assign({
      c: 34,
      d: 'something else'
    },
    first
  )
}

console.log(container)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:**

In fact you are assigning the content of `second` with `undefined`, because at the time you are trying to refer the `first` property, at the assignement time, **it doesn't exist yet in your `container` object**.

**Solution:**

You need either to store the content of `first` property in an `object` before the assignement or create your `container` object with only `first` property and then define `container.second` property to get `first` value combined with `second` value.

This is how can be your code:

```js
var container = {
  first: {
    a: 1,
    b: 'someString'
  }
};

container.second = Object.assign({
    c: 34,
    d: 'something else'
  },
  container.first
);

console.log(container)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may looking for this.

```js
var a = new function(){
    this.b = {name:"Vignesh",place:"India"};
    this.c = {name:"Vijay",place:"TamilNadu",b:this.b};
    this.d = {name:"Vijay Sethupathi",place:"Namakkal",c:this.c};
}();
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var container = {
    first: {
        a: 1,
        b: 'someString'
    }
}

container.second = Object.assign(
    {
        c: 34,
        d: 'Something else'
    },
    container.first
)
```

Comment: You might want to elaborate on what you changed and why this is solving the problem.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.