# using this keyword as a way to pass an argument to a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
var now = 2018;

function calculateAge(yearOfBirth) {
    return now - yearOfBirth;
}

var Josh = {
    dateOfBirth: 1990,
    age: calculateAge(this.dateOfBirth),
}

console.log(Josh.age);
```

Why can't I use a key as an argument in a function? If I put normal number there it works fine but I can't understand why that way doesn't. Does it have something to do with recursion or scope?

Comment: Your code can be simplified to: `var Josh = { foo: 42, bar: this.foo }; console.log(Josh.bar);`

Comment: that's not really what I asked for

Comment: No, it's what you should have come up with as part of preparing a [mcve].

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can a Javascript object refer to values in itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself)

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that in this statement:

```
var Josh = {
    dateOfBirth: 1990,
    age: calculateAge(this.dateOfBirth),
}
```

`this` does not refer to `Josh`, or to the object that will become `Josh`. There's no way it could, because none of these things exist yet when this statement executes.

In this statement `this` refers to whatever it refers to in any other statement in that scope.

```
console.log(this);                         // <-- same this
var Josh = {
    dateOfBirth: 1990,
    age: calculateAge(this.dateOfBirth),   // <-- same this
}
console.log(this.someProperty);            // <-- same this
```

If the `this` in that scope doesn't have a `dateOfBirth` property of `1990`, you're not going to get the result you're expecting.

If you want to avoid having to repeat the `1990` value, then store it in a variable, and reference that variable:

```
var dob = 1990;
var Josh = {
    dateOfBirth: dob,
    age: calculateAge(dob)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other *good answers*, you could also achieve the behaviour you're looking for by simply having a *getter* for the age property:

```
function calculateAge(yearOfBirth) {
    return 2018 - yearOfBirth;
}

var Josh = {
    dateOfBirth: 1990,
    get age() {
        return calculateAge(this.dateOfBirth);
    }
}

Josh.age; // > 28
```

An additional bonus to this approach is that `Josh.age` is calculated in real-time when accessed, and thus it will always be in sync with `Josh.dateOfBirth`:

```
Josh.age; // > 28
Josh.dateOfBirth = 1988;
Josh.age; // > 30
```

Answer (score 0):

## The problem

**For example:**  *Imagine this is the only line of code in your Javascript file*

```
// In web browsers, the window object is also the global object:
console.log(this === window); // true
```

The example above shows how `this` behaves, the value of `this` dependents of its context.

The use of `this` in your code isn't referencing to your object `Josh` it's referencing to either the current called function or global context.

If you try to print `this` as follow `console.log(this)` you will realize that `this` has a value from a different context than `Josh`'s.

## The solution

- Create an instantiable Object with those attributes, and you will be able to use `this` which has `Josh`'s context:

```
var Josh = function() {
   this.dateOfBirth = 1990,
   this.age = calculateAge(this.dateOfBirth)
};
```

**Look this code snippet:**

```js
var now = 2018;

function calculateAge(yearOfBirth) {
  return now - yearOfBirth;
}

var Josh = function() {
  this.dateOfBirth = 1990,
  this.age = calculateAge(this.dateOfBirth)
};

console.log(new Josh().age);
```

See, now it's passing the right value to your function `calculateAge`.

Comment: Why the downvotes? just to understand what's wrong with this answer.

Comment: Note, did not cast "downvote". "The problem" is described at Answer by @JLRishe

Comment: @guest271314 I agree with JLRishe's answer.

Comment: I didn't downvote either, but I will say that while using an instantiable object is one way to accomplish what OP is trying to do, his/her non-use of one is not the problem.

Answer (score -2):

Give it a try,

```
var now = 2018;

var Josh = {
    dateOfBirth: 1990,
    age: function () {
        return (now - this.dateOfBirth);
    }
}

console.log(Josh.age())
```