# React Native - refer key in the same object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a collection of URL's, that I want to use as a constant file in my React-Native app.

```
export default {
  HTTP_HOST: 'http://192.168.1.5',
  SIGNUP_API: this.HTTP_HOST+'/services/registerMobileNumber.php',
};
```

When I import constant.js like below

```
import GLOBAL from '../../constant.js';
```

`GLOBAL.HTTP_HOST` works fine, 
but `GLOBAL.SIGNUP_API` gives `undefined/services/registerMobileNumber.php`

How can I refer the key HTTP_HOST in the same object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by two method
1. Don't reference it by this use the OUTER Variable Name like:

```
const SERVICES = {
             HTTP_HOST:'http://192.168.1.5',
             SIGNUP_API: SERVICES.HTTP_HOST+'/monopoly/services/registerMobileNumber.php'
        };
export default SERVICES;
```

2. You can use custom getter and setter for key SIGNUP_API.

   ```
   const SERVICES = {
     HTTP_HOST:'http://192.168.1.5',
     get SIGNUP_API() {
       return this.HTTP_HOST+'/monopoly/services/registerMobileNumber.php'
     }
   }
   export default SERVICES;
   ```

Now both of the method will give you same output. For Example -

```
import GLOBAL from '../../constant.js';
console.log(GLOBAL.SIGNUP_API)
```

gives the output,
http://192.168.1.5/monopoly/services/registerMobileNumber.php

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript (JSON) does not allow you to do this. However, you do have quite a few options of other ways to accomplish the desired behavior:

[How can a Javascript object refer to values in itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there was no solution to this..

So I tried this and it worked.

```
const HTTP_HOST = 'http://192.168.1.5';

const SERVICES = {
    SIGNUP_API: HTTP_HOST+'/monopoly/services/registerMobileNumber.php'
}

export default SERVICES;
```