# knockoutjs: i am having this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to cast an object into an observable, but then my computed function is not working

```
onlineFriends.friend = function(data) {

    var item = {

        country : ko.observable(data.country),

        firstName : ko.observable("oto"),

        userName  : ko.observable(data.username),

        id : ko.observable(data.id),

        picture : ko.observable(data.picture),

        hasInitMessage : ko.observable(false),

        messages : ko.observableArray([]),

        hasInitMessage : ko.observable(false),

        unreadmessages_count : ko.computed(function() {

            var unreadMsg = [];

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(item.messages(), function (item) {

                if(item.messageStatus === "UNREAD"){

                    unreadMsg.push(item);
                }

            });

            return unreadMsg.length;

        }),

        //onlineFriends.friendsOnline.push(self);

}

return item;

};
```

i understand it complaining about the message() observable array i want to loop through, but then how can i write the code.

Comment: The answers to [this question on objects referring to themselves](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself) might help

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the computed declaration to this

```
  unreadmessages_count : ko.computed(function() {    
            var unreadMsg = [];

            ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.messages(), function (item) {    
                if(item.messageStatus === "UNREAD")  
                    unreadMsg.push(item);             
            });

            return unreadMsg.length;

        },this)
```

I would guess the scoping gets messed up with your current implementation