# confusing js objects propertis

Tags: javascript, methods, properties

```js
var dataset = { num: 20 };
var svg = { w: 600 };
var column = {
    padding: 0.2,
    w: (svg.w/dataset.num)/(this.padding + 1),
    print: function(){
      console.log("through obj methord:" +
      (svg.w/dataset.num)/(this.padding + 1)
      );}
    };
column.print();
console.log(column);
```

above is the code, and it could be executed, and in the result, you could see the result of *column.w* is *NAN*, while the same calculation in the obj's method: *print* could give back the right answer: 25.

how could it be? even though i replaced **(svg.w/dataset.num)/(this.padding + 1)** by **svg.w/(dataset.num*(this.padding + 1))** ,it is exactly the same.
    after i replace the variables like svg.w, dataset.num with its values, column.w becomes value 25 of course.

Comment: without knowing what your `this` variable reffers to, it's hard to tell.

Comment: if you replace your w: ..... with w: function() {return (svg.w/dataset.num)/(this.padding + 1); and then call it with column.w() it will work

Comment: yeah, I have done it already,  i just confuse why @Bolphgolph

Comment: @HuangQinlai I recommend you read the answers under this Question https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787621/7241459

Comment: @Bolphgolph thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the `this.padding` to the value 0.25.

Javascript does not know what your `this` variable reffers to.

> The “this” variable is a variable that each and every execution context gets, in a regular function call the “this” variable points at the global object or the window in the browser, which is the default. In a method call, which is a function within a variable, the “this” variable points at the method calling the object. The “this” variable is not assigned a value until the function where it is defined is actually called.

When you are using `this` in your code, it still points to the object which method you called. That object does not have a `padding` property, that's why your calculation can not be executed.

Read more about the `this` variable [here](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/javascript-this-variable-c49723cdea71)

Comment: you mean only in functions, *this* keyword will know which object it refers to?

Comment: thank you, because this is a default global variable in the property, so it can't refer to the *column* object. and I also tried to replace *this* with *column*, and it says column is undefined without running over the column definition statement,  so I think I should use the method when need *this*