# Javascript Object: Setting a value to be equal to a previous Key

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

In javascript, is there anyway to set a value equal to a previous key that was declared during initialization?
for example,

```js
const object = {
  a: "test",
  b: a
    }
 
 console.log(object)
```

or

```js
const object = {
  a: "test",
  b: object.a
    }
 
 console.log(object)
```

How can I achieve this result in the console?

```js
    { a: 'test', b: 'test' }
```

I understand that this is redundant, so let me explain what I'm trying to achieve.

I want to be able to set a url in one value, and then add to it using a previous value. The reason for this is to clean up the code and set formulas into one object.

Example

```js
const object = {
  base_url: "www.google.com",
  images_url: `${base_url}/images`,
  maps_url: `${base_url}/maps`
    }
 
 console.log(object)
```

Comment: Isn’t this a bit redundant? Curious, can you elaborate on your use case for which you would need this kind of functionality?

Comment: you can't do it at the same time as object initialization.

Comment: This is not doable. You can't refer an object during its initialisation.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787245/how-can-a-javascript-object-refer-to-values-in-itself/2787259

Comment: You can't do it during initialization, but you can afterwards. `var object = { a: "test" }; object.b = object.a;`

Comment: You can have a getter that refers to another field. Looks like a field to the client code.

Comment: Declare the google Variable outside the object and then inside properties just use it. This is a safe way where you know your variable is not changing (which is why i guess you are trying to refer to the same value). There is no better way to do it the way you want

Comment: If you're willing to change it from an object to a class you could achieve something like this in the constructor; might make sense depending on your use case.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I can think of in Javascript is to use a [getter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

```js
const object = {
  a: "test",
  get b(){
   return this.a+"something else";
  }
    }
 
console.log(object)
```

Answer (score 3):

Getter/Setters will save your day

```js
const object = {
  a: "test",
  get b(){return this.a}
 }
 
 console.log(object)
```